# What's the concept behind using putty with three at signs in the hostname

Tags: ssh, putty

I was told to use putty with a certain syntax when specifying the target host:
[image: Putty Config / hostname]

I can not use `myuser@destinationserver.com` but have to use a string like `myuser@someotheruser@destinationserver.com@somekindofintermediateserver.com`.
The reason to this seems to be that for security reasons the company I work at uses CyberArk.

What's the name of that concept ? I heard of "bastion host", "ssh Proxy" or "jump server".
And is it possible to tell putty that when talking to "myuser@destinationserver.com" it needs to "rewrite" the host and mix in the other user and hostname ? I know that `ssh` is able to handle this kind of Information in its config file.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit late with my answer, but since I spent some time today debunking myths and understanding poorly written internal PowerPoint documentation, which was even worse than you think, let's try to explain some things as we can observe them now.

> What's the name of that concept ? I heard of "bastion host", "ssh Proxy" or "jump server".

All of them should be correct. Cyberark calls this product or component in their offering [Privileged Session Manager](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/Latest/en/Content/PAS%20SysReq/System%20Requirements%20-%20PSM.htm). The documents I read also called it a hardened jump host or gateway.

The string with three @ signs looks unusual, but you could actually add a [fourth](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/latest/en/Content/PASIMP/PSSO-PMSP.htm#The) @ in some cases. That would be `@targetpassword` then. Remember never to sumbit passwords in plain text as a parameter on the CLI. There are also `#` when some customers implement the product as you can see in the documentation. These are simply used as [delimiters](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/latest/en/Content/PASIMP/Configuring-PSMP-Syntax-Delimiters.htm) from parameters and you can customize them if you need to.

Anyways, what happens here with all the at signs? Parsing, I guess. The last part is the (jump) host name, the first part is the (jump host) user name and everything in between gets passed to the environment where the actual server is you want to administer. Using `.ssh/config` users found putting all the parameters expect the last part, the host name, into the user field to [work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359600/ssh-config-file-and-username-for-cyberark).

I remember network architects complaining about GUI tools made with IPv4 in mind and thus terribly failing at IPv6. Which sounds quite similar. I have no time to dig further if there is a formal specification of what is allowed (to work) and what not. But I guess that such a thing exists.

I thought I could dig up something in the OpenSSH and (mirrored) PuTTY repositories on Github, but apparently it's standards compliant to not trip any (popular) SSH client over and to get the job done.

Note: I am surprised how least intrusive the product can be when you just focus on your work as terminal only Linux admin. I heard a lot of complaining, but when you are not obsessed with clicking all day to get your work done then there is no friction at all and I got past my initial complaints with 5 lines of code in git-bash on an Windows system.

---

Edit 2022-09-11:

> And is it possible to tell putty that when talking to "myuser@destinationserver.com" it needs to "rewrite" the host and mix in the other user and hostname ?

On second thought, and putting it in precise words, Cyberark like a few others (Teleport comes to my mind) implemented their own proprietary SSH solution. They could require you to do all kinds of things, but they chose to be compatible with existing solutions, so they tell you to pass all parameters in the user name field and their gateway, knowing which delimiters to apply, deserializes all the parameters to identify were you want to jump to. Quite nifty. No I wouldn't call it a standard, unless an (Open)SSH maintainer weighs in tells me I'm wrong. Yes it looks confusing, but it works.